# using java8 stream api to convert one object to another

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, dto

I am developing a SpringBoot project.

I have a `Car` model class:

```
public class Car {
   private String plateNumber;
   private CarType type;
   private String brand
}
```

There is a `CarType` enum:

```
public enum CarType {
   HATCH_BACK, SEDAN, SUV
}
```

In my DTO layer, I have a `CarDTO` class:

```
public class CarDTO {
       private String plateNumber;
       private String type;
       private String brand
}
```

(The only difference between `Car` and `CarDTO` is that in `CarDTO` the `type` property is a `String` whereas in `Car` the `type` property is a `CarType`).

In Controller, I got a List of CarDTO in request payload:

```
List<CarDTO> carsFromReq = request.getCars();
```

I would like to get a `List<Car>` out from `List<CarDTO>`, how to achieve that with Java8 stream API?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Create an all argument constructor in CarDTO.
You can use `@AllArgsConstructor` of lombok for all argument constructor.

Then create CarDTO object in `.map()`

```
List<CarDTO> carsFromReq = request.getCars().stream()
    .map(car-> new CarDTO(car.getPlateNumber(),car.getType().name(),car.getBrand()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Did you try this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). It generates the mapper implementations statically, so you don't have to map each and every field manually.

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CarMapper.class);

    Car map(CarDTO car);

    CarDTO map(Car car);

    List<CarDTO> map(Iterable<Car> car);

    List<Car> mapDtos(Iterable<CarDTO> car);

}
```

Then you can use a it as simple as follows:

```
 CarDTO dto = CarMapper.INSTANCE.map(car);
 // ...
 Car car2 = CarMapper.INSTANCE.map(dto);
 // ...
 List<Car> cars = CarMapper.INSTANCE.mapDtos(dtos);
 // ...
 List<CarDTO> dtos = CarMapper.INSTANCE.map(cars);
```

---

Note:
Actually the official [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) site has an example pretty similar to your one.